# How to make a loop in dictionary to extract values?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping a page. I made two `loops` but the first loop is only taking `transcription_price` value not the last two one. Why and how to solve this problem?

```
def start_requests(self):
    links = {'transcription_page': 'https://www.rev.com/freelancers/transcription',
             'captions_page': 'https://www.rev.com/freelancers/captions',
             'subtitles_page': 'https://www.rev.com/freelancers/subtitles'
            }
    call = [self.parse_transcription,self.parse_caption,self.parse_subtitles]

    for link in links.values():
        for n in range(0,3):
            return [scrapy.Request(link, callback=call[n])]
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `return` statement, well, returns the value and terminates<sup>1</sup> the function, passing the control flow to the caller. This way, your inner loop is terminated before it goes over all the values.

Perhaps what you wanted was `yield`:

```py
>>> def f():
...  for x in (1, 2, 3):
...   yield x
...
>>> list(f())
[1, 2, 3]
```

Besides, using unnamed constants is a way to plant a bug which is often not so obvious, not to say non-Pythonic:

```py
items = ["a", "b", "c"]

# will make an incomplete round when `items` is longer than 3 elements
def poor():
  for i in xrange(0, 3):
    yield items[i]

# will do just alright
def appropriate():
  for item in items:
    yield item
```

<sup>1</sup> Unless you are in `try/except/finally` block, in which case `finally` is always executed before `return` takes place:

```py
def return_one():
  try:
    1/0
  except ZeroDivisionError:
    return 0
  finally:
    return 1
```

Comment: I always forget about `yield`. Perhaps a generator is exactly what OP wanted!

Comment: I didn't understand.

Comment: @Dania the way you initially wrote it, the first executed `return` of your function will break the loop and return a single value from it. To obtain multiple values, you need to either insert them in a list variable and return it instead or use a generator with `yield` keyword in place of `return`, as shown in my example.

Comment: I yield it and I also insert them in a list variable but it didn't work.